# jQuery var background map issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var set = "1";

var settings = {

    images: {
        'images/set' + set + '/bg01.jpg': 'center',
        'images/set' + set + '/bg02.jpg': 'center',
        'images/set' + set + '/bg03.jpg': 'center',
        'images/set' + set + '/bg04.jpg': 'center',
        'images/set' + set + '/bg05.jpg': 'center'
    },
    delay: 6000
};
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the `+ set +`. It needs an outcome like "set1", so I can easily adjust it, but it doesn't work.

Searched like an hour for a solution to this. Someone please help me out with this.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Before posting, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign properties to the images object based on the value of a variable, you should use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to reference the properties. Try this:

```
var set = "1";
var settings = {
            images: {},
            delay: 6000
};
settings.images['images/set' + set + '/bg01.jpg'] = 'center';
settings.images['images/set' + set + '/bg02.jpg'] = 'center';
settings.images['images/set' + set + '/bg03.jpg'] = 'center';
```

Comment: I'm glad! If this solves your issue please consider marking it as the accepted answer. ([See this for a description on what are accepted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work))